# Play Framework 2 slugify

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I want to slugify an object's String attr to use it in urls. 
I've read that there was a function called "slugify" in play 1.x, but i can't find it in play 2.x

What's the best method to slugify a String in play 2.x?

If i have to implement the function (or any helper function like this) where should I place it for best accessibility for the whole mvc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/r-raDXl95Q4, there is no builtin slugify helper in Play 2. But it's easy enough to build your own. Here's one example:

https://github.com/julienrf/chooze/blob/master/app/util/Util.scala#L6

The author places the helper under `app/util`, which is as reasonable a place as any, IMO.

Comment: i'll implement the function in java. can i use scala and java mixed in somehow? i'm new to play framework and scala as you see :)

Comment: Java and Scala are interoperable. However, if you intend to use Scala features that aren't available in Java (e.g., traits, objects, etc.), you'll have some naming issues to work around.